# NativeScript DatePickerField: How to pass additional parameters together with the changed date

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am using [nativescript-datetimepicker](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-datetimepicker) with [nativescript-vue](https://nativescript-vue.org/) and on `@dateChange` event I would like to pass not only the changed date, but also some parameters. The standard way to do this is:

```
<DatePickerField @dateChange="onDateChange"></DatePickerField>

methods: {
    onDateChange(args) {
        console.log('Here is the new date: ', args.value)
    },
}
```

But it is not possible to do something like this:

```
<DatePickerField @dateChange="onDateChange(args, param1, param2)"></DatePickerField>

methods: {
    onDateChange(args, param1, param2) {
        console.log('Here is the new date: ', args.value)
        console.log('Here is param1: ', param1)
        console.log('Here is param1: ', param1)
    },
}
```

Comment: what about `@dateChange="onDateChange($event, param1, param2)"`? in this case `$event` refers to the selected date

Comment: I already tried it and it crashed the first time as I only passed `$event`, but now works with `$event.value`, strange, but thanks anyway!